# Xcode : Alamofire get String response

Tags: xcode, alamofire

I am new in IOS development and currently learning networking with Alamofire

i am trying to make a login ...
whenever the credentials are correct the .php file returns a `json` and i am able to get that json from `Alamofire` through the following code:

```
    Alamofire.request(loginUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        print("String:\(response.result.value)")
        switch(response.result) {
        case .success(_):
            if let data = response.result.value{
                print(self.loginUrl)
                print(data)
            }

        case .failure(_):

            print(self.loginUrl)
            print("failed")
            print("Error message:\(response.result.error)")
            break

        }
    }
```

now...when ever the credentials are wrong, the .php does't give the json..instead it return a string ..for example "wrong_password" or "userLocked" etc etc...
how can i get the String response through Alamofire?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want **JSON** response use **.responseJSON** , if you want **String** response use **.responseString**. If you want both use both. Hope this help.

```
Alamofire.request(loginUrl, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
     .responseJSON { response in
       print("JSON:\(response.result.value)")
       switch(response.result) {
       case .success(_):
          if let data = response.result.value{
             print(data)
           }
            
        case .failure(_):
            
            print("Error message:\(response.result.error)")
            break
            
        }
    }
     .responseString { response in
       print("String:\(response.result.value)")
       switch(response.result) {
       case .success(_):
          if let data = response.result.value{
             print(data)
            }
                
       case .failure(_):
           print("Error message:\(response.result.error)")
           break     
        }
    }
```

**UPDATED: Swift 5, Alamofire 5**

```
    AF.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print("response: \(response)")
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                print("value**: \(value)")
                
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
    }
    .responseString { response in
        print("response: \(response)")
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print("value**: \(value)")
            
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: you didn't get what my point is....i am saying that i can get different strings as a response too ...like wrong_password,userlocked,etc etc and if password and username matches then i will get json...how can i get the string response? i my case i want to print wrong_password or userlocked or any string i got from php

Comment: what **data** do you get in **print(data)** when the credentials are wrong in the log ?

Comment: thats the point...in log it always get to .failure it never gets to .success because the data i get on wrong credentials is not json..its simple a string/..."wrong_password"

Comment: So as I can see you want **JSON** & **String** both return when the response is successful, so use both. I have updated my answer.

Comment: thank you..can you write all the alamofire code? so can i could understand well? that would be pretty helpfull

Comment: Try this book to learn everything about **Alamofire** with **Swift**, this is the best book so far I have read, [iOS Apps with REST](https://leanpub.com/iosappswithrest) , also do not forget to accept the answer if that helps you. Thanks

Comment: This response is outdated, please update if possible.

Comment: Updated @PedroPauloAmorim

Answer (score 4):

I resolve this by:

```
print(response.request)  // original URL request
print(response.response) // URL response
print(response.data)     // server data
print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
```

source:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/818