# How to get and save the response in swift5 and Alamofire 5 beta version?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I tried some code but still, my issue is not resolved. Please help me i am new in swift code.

```
let parameters: Parameters = ["skey": "XXXXXX","country_code":"91","mobile":"XXX004","user_role":"4"]


 AF.request("http://XXXXX/dev/clinic/api/v1/login_otp?", method: .get, parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                let status = JSON["status"] as! String
                print(status)
            }
        case .failure(let error): break
            // error handling
        }
}
```

bellow is the server responce

```
 success({
      message = "Otp sent successfully on +9170XXXX1004";
      status = 1;
})
```

Comment: What is your problem..Please explain it more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode : Alamofire get String response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095161/xcode-alamofire-get-string-response)

Comment: what was the issue u faced.

Comment: I am unable to print the status.

Comment: if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any]  here i am getting error "Value of type 'Result<Any, Error>' has no member 'value'"

Comment: I did try this code and it works well for me. Which version of Alamofire do you use?

Comment: @Vladlex can u check my updated image

Comment: @SivaSankar I see now. Please, tell which version of Swift and Alamofire do you use?

Comment: swift5 and alamofire 5

Comment: @SivaSankar Alamofire 5.0 is currently in beta. 
I've downloaded the latest release (  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-beta.5'). There is no "value" method there. Try the code from my answer below (put it in a separate answer to make it easy to read)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the following code, please:

```
         switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    if let JSON = value as? [String: Any] {
                        let status = JSON["status"] as! String
                        print(status)
                    }
                case .failure(let error): break
                    // error handling
                }
```

Comment: @SivaSankar I'm sorry, check the code again, I've made a fix =)

`let JSON = value as? [String: Any]`

Answer (score 20):

For Alamo 5 you have to use:

```
response.value
```

Comment: This was the fix; changed from response.result.value to this in AlamoFire 5

Comment: Thanks... I've been looking for a solution for ages.. This was so easy and quick!

Answer (score 0):

The error Value of type 'Result' has no member 'value' is due to Alamofire version 5, in version 4.8.2 Result is of type Result of type < Any>

If you have installed Alamofire through pod, then you should get version 4.8.2 where your code works fine.

```
Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1", method: .get)
        .responseJSON { (response) in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
                    let status = JSON["completed"] as! Bool
                    print(status)
                }



            case .failure(_): break

            }
    }
```

In this case Result< Any> type not Result< Any, Error>
And use Alamofire instead of AF

Comment: in my Xcode pod install has some problem. if u have any version of alamofire can u please share to me.

Comment: @SivaSankar you don't need to mention the version of Alamofire in Podfile in my Podfile I simply mention pod 'Alamofire', By default, it will install latest stable version 4.8.2. Mark my answer as working, if it works and let me know.