# Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I am trying to get JSON data from the API &  I want to print it on the terminal to check whether I am receiving data on my terminal or not but I am getting this error. I am currently using Swift 5 .

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
typealias JSON = [String: Any]

class NetworkingService {
    static let shared = NetworkingService()
    private init() {}

    func getPeople(completion: () -> Void) {
        AF.request("https://launchlibrary.net/1.4/launchstatus").responseJSON{ (response) in

            if let json = response.result.value as? JSON { // here I am getting error
                print(json)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: [It doesn't have `value` indeed](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Result%2BAlamofire.swift)

Comment: What error you’re facing??

Comment: @PratikPrajapati see the question label

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I saw this but couldn't make it

Comment: Alternative, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57088201/how-to-get-and-save-the-response-in-swift5-and-alamofire-5-beta-version

Answer (score 14):

Replace your request completion block with:

```swift
switch response.result {
case let .success(value):
    print(value)
case let .failure(error):
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: which line should i remove ?

Comment: the block `if let json = ... }`